# How to fix compiler error: CS0841 - Cannot use local variable before it is declared, when variable has already been declared outside the loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I get a CS0841 compiler error for 3 different variables that are already initialized outside their respective conditional statements. At first I thought it was a simple issue of having my brackets in the wrong place but after double checking my code, it looks like the code within the loop just doesn't recognize the initialization of the variable outside the loop or if statement. Why do I get this issue?

```
//Simplified version of the code. It doesn't make as much sense simplified but this highlights my //issues more clearly. 

if(R > 10) { 
int [,] MRold = new int[R, 14]; // MRold is declared here. 
//rest of if statement.....
}
else{
//the else condition......
}

int k = 1; //k is declared.

for(int i = 0; i < MRarray.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
    if(R > 10) {
        for(int j = 0; j < MRold.GetUpperBound(0); j++) { //MRold here throws the 0841 error
            int oo; //oo declared
            for(int CC = 8; CC <= Rows; CC++) {
                oo = CC;
                break;
            }
            // A couple other conditional statements/loops here, and nested within them is this:
                for(int jj = 2; jj <= 14; jj++) { 
                    OutArray[k, jj] = OutArray[k, jj] + Increment; // k throws the error
                    OutArray2[oo, jj] = OutputArray2[oo, jj] + Increment; // oo throws error.
                    break;
                }
            // I close the aforementioned other loops/statements here.
        }
    }
}
//Basically my issue is the innermost loops can't access the declared variables within outer 
//loops or loops/conditions that came before the one they are nested in.
//Also want to note that instances of MRold/oo/k that occur after the very first one that throws the //error don't throw an error. Only the first instance of the declared variable throws an error //within the loop/conditional statement. The rest of the instances do not throw the same error. 
//They compile fine.
```

Comment: You may know or believe that `R>10` being false the first time may also mean that it's also false the second time but the compiler isn't required and would often be unable to know the same. So if that test is indeed false the first time and true the second you're trying to access `MRold` that has never been initialised. I'd strongly advise that even this "simplified" code looks too complex to actually try and all be in one method.

Comment: The scope of `MRold` is the `if`statement, after te closing `}` the variable is gone.

Comment: Also, errors are a compile time concept and are emitted by the compiler. Exceptions are a runtime concept and are thrown by our code or the runtime. Errors aren't thrown.

Comment: Initialize `oo`: `int oo = 0;` or any other value, the compiler doesn't infer that `oo` will be assigned since `for(int CC = 8; CC <= Rows; CC++)` will be run at least once.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Good point about errors vs. exceptions. I was asked to simplify the code by someone else I asked to take a look at the full file as well, particularly for maintainability. So no worries, that will be my next step once I get this working, to make it a sustainable application by anyone who needs to add to or edit it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick amendment is to initialize `oo`, e.g.

```
// Rain or shine, oo is assigned 
int oo = 0;

for (int CC = 8; CC <= Rows; CC++) {
  // oo can be change under some conditions
  oo = CC;

  break;
}

...

// oo is guaranteed to have a value assigned
OutArray2[oo, jj] = OutputArray2[oo, jj] + Increment;
```

since compiler doesn't understand that since `for` loop will be run at least once, `oo` will be assigned before its first usage. The next stage is to think on do you want the `for` loop at all? You `break` just after the entry: `int CC = 8; ... oo = CC; break;`, why don't you put it as

```
int oo = 8;
```

Check if `Increment` is assigned as well (I can't see `Increment` declaration in your code)

Comment: Increment was declared elsewhere in the code and thankfully didn't give me any issues or errors. I do need the for loop here. I didn't include it but there's an if statement after the for loop before the break so it looks something like this: for (int CC = 8; CC <= Rows; CC++) { if(ProgName == OArray[CC, 1].ToString()) { oo = CC; break;} } I left the if statement out for simplicity's sake but you're completely correct I wouldn't need the for, if the if statement wasn't there.